# Is there any free vector editing software?

Tags: vector, software-recommendation, free

Is a free vector editing software similar to Illustrator?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are several. My go-to software is Inkscape mainly due to its stability: https://inkscape.org/en/

There's also the drawing tool from OpenOffice/LibreOffice if you feel like you need to create vector art in a Microsoft Word style interface.

If you need CMYK support there's SK1, though I personally haven't tried it so I can't vouch for it: http://sk1project.org/

Comment: I took a look at the latest Inkscape and it looks like it now supports CMYK. So I highly recommend giving Inkscape a try.